# algorithm2e is numbered by 2 for each line

Tags: algorithm2e

The following algorithm has lines numbered by 2. I simply need them to start at 1 and go by 1: 1,2,3,4 etc. Why is this happening? Thanks and Regards,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,lined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\title{Algo}
\author{}
\date{February 2022}
\begin{document}
\vspace{1cm}
\SetNlSty{textbf}{}{:}
\IncMargin{1em}
\setcounter{algocf}{1}
\begin{algorithm}[H]

\nl first line\

\nl second line\

\nl third line \

\BlankLine
\caption{My caption.}\label{alg:cap}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Remove `\setcounter{algocf}{1}`.

Comment: this line makes the algorithm name start at 2, but not the line numbers. If we remove it we have Algorithm 1 instead of Algorithm 2 (which I need), but the lines will still go 2,4,6...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. (different setup options)

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[commentsnumbered, ruled]{algorithm2e} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\title{Algo}
\author{}
\date{February 2022}
\begin{document}
\vspace{1cm}
\SetNlSty{textbf}{}{:}
\IncMargin{1em}
\setcounter{algocf}{1}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    
    \nl first line\
    
    \nl second line\
    
    \nl third line \
    
    \BlankLine
    \caption{My caption.}\label{alg:cap1}
\end{algorithm}

    \begin{algorithm}[H]
    
    \nl first line\
    
    \nl second line\
    
    \nl third line \
    
    \BlankLine
    \caption{My caption.}\label{alg:cap2}
\end{algorithm} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Somethink like this? I hope to understand well your question.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,lined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\title{Algo}
\author{}
\date{February 2022}
\begin{document}
\vspace{1cm}
\SetNlSty{textbf}{}{:}
\IncMargin{1em}
\setcounter{algocf}{1}
\begin{algorithm}[H]

 first line\

second line\

 third line \

\BlankLine
\caption{My caption.}\label{alg:cap}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed `linesnumbered` and let only the `lined` package.
Additionally, I set `\setcounter{AlgoLine}{0}` after `\begin{algorithm}[H]`, to ensure the lines start at a specified number. This is useful to me as I have many algorithms following one another, and I need the lines to restart at `1` for each algorithm.